# How boto3.s3.transfer handles multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, boto3

I am uploading to S3 using below code:

```
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024)
transfer= S3Transfer(s3_client, config)
transfer.upload_file(fileadded, bucket, key,callback=ProgressPercentage(file))
```

I couldnt get anything on how internally boto handles multipart upload.
I have few questions regarding the same, lets assume I have 2.5 MB file:

1. Then the file will it be uploaded in 3 parts like 1, 1 and .5 MB?
2. All the 3 parts will be uploaded in parallel or sequential?
3. In aws library for java we have TransferManager, any similar thing in boto?
4. If this code sufficient for multi part uploads? Because I came across some complicated code samples for the same

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The S3 transfer will use the config you created to transfer the files.  Check the [documentation on TransferConfig](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig) to see the parameters you can set and their defaults.

To answer your questions:

1. yes
2. parallel, using threads
3. boto3 uses [s3transfer](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer)
   internally, but normally you would just use the `TransferConfig`
4. yes